# Deriving Sample version of Anderson Darling test statistic from the theoretical version

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference, nonparametric, goodness-of-fit

In literature, I have seen two types of Anderson-Darling test statistic. One is expressed as

$A_T^2 = n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(F_n(x)-F(x))^2}{F(x)(1-F(x))}dF(x)$ and the other is given by $A_s^2 = -n-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2i-1}{n}[\ln F(Y_i)+\ln(1-F(Y_{n+1-i}))]$, where $Y_1, Y_2,\cdots, Y_n$ are ordered samples.

My question is, how do we get $A^2_s$ from $A_T^2$? My guess is we have to solve a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, but I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840822/prove-the-computational-formula-of-anderson-darling-test-statistic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U_{in}:= F(X_{in});$ for brevity though, we would write $u_i$ in place of $u_{in};$ take $u_0=0,~u_{n+1} = 1.$ Define $\psi(x):= [x(1-x)]^{-1}.$

Anderson-Darling statistic is given by $W_n^2:= n\int [S_n(x)-F(x)]^2\psi(F(x))~\mathrm dF(x).$

Then $$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\frac{W_n^2}n&=\sum_{i=0}^n \int_{u_i}^{u_{i+1}} \left(\frac i n - u\right)^2~\psi(u)~\mathrm du\\ &= \sum_{i=0}^n \left[\frac{ i^2 }{n^2}\ln u-u -\left(\frac{i}{n}-1\right)^2 \ln(1-u)
 \right]_{u_i}^{u_{i+1}}\\&= \left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i^2}{n^2}\ln u_{i+1}- \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i^2}{n^2}\ln u_{i}\right]-\left[\underbrace{u_{n+1}}_{=1} +\cancel{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} u_{i+1}} -\cancel{\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i}}\right]-\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac i n -1\right)^2\ln(1-u_{i+1}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac i n -1\right)^2\ln(1-u_{i})\right]\\&= -1+\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(i-1)^2}{n^2}\ln u_{i}- \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i^2}{n^2}\ln u_{i}\right] -\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{ i^2}{ n^2} \ln(1-u_{i+1}) -2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac i n\ln(1-u_{i+1}) +\cancel{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ln (1-u_{i+1})} -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{ i^2}{ n^2} \ln(1-u_{i})+2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac i n\ln(1-u_{i}) - \cancel{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln (1-u_{i})} \right]\\ &= -1-\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(2i-1)}{n^2}\ln u_i\right]- \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{ (i-1)^2}{ n^2} \ln(1-u_{i})- \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{ i^2}{ n^2} \ln(1-u_{i})-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac {(i-1)}{ n}\ln(1-u_{i})+ 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac {i}{ n}\ln(1-u_{i}) \right]\\ &=-1- \left[\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(2i-1)}{n^2}\ln u_i\right] -\left[-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{ (2i-1)}{ n^2} \ln(1-u_{i})+ \frac{2}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}n\ln(1-u_{i})\right]\\ &=-1- \left[\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(2i-1)}{n^2}\ln u_i\right] -\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{ (2n-2i+1)}{ n^2} \ln(1-u_{i})\right]\\ &= -1- \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(2i-1)}{n^2}\left[\ln u_i + \ln(1-u_{n-i+1})\right]. \end{align} $$